# Post request to API shows error when posting special character in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, api, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am calling this method from Login Provider file. I have two input fields username and password. It works fine to connect with API. But when I am using any '+' sign in my password it shows error! And failed to connect with API.

Passwords with no Error

> password: '584526564'

Passwords which shows Error

> password: '4568466+45787'

```
login(user) {    
    let dt = "grant_type=password&username=" + user.username + "&password=" + user.password;    
    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };    
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl, dt, { headers }).subscribe(
      res => {
        alert("Student Saved!");
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        alert("Error!");
      });    
  }
```

Error message in console
[image: Console Error]

Comment: **+** in _query params_ are treated as _encoding for spaces_. So you  need to encode it and send.

Comment: But API is not my hand. So can't decode it again! @inizio

Comment: My suggestion will be not to allow + symbol

Comment: But I have existing data with '+' sign.

Comment: This is the know issue. You can refer [Github - Angular Passing special characters Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20376)